Lock formula code affecting other vba codes not to run properly
I have a workbook with 5 sheets which are full of formulas and I need to make them safe uneditable. I have found through Stackoverflow a simple code that protects formulas and it's working good but it has two issues.. first it affects the other codes in my workbook not to run properly such as inserting images based on a cell value - my images stopped to be updated when I change a cell value. and also gives me error(1004) when i edit some unlocked cells but included in other codes ranges.. I dont know how to fix that. any sugesstions please ?... here in below my code
Sub LockSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            .Unprotect
            .Cells.Locked = False
            .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
            .Protect
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub



Set UserInterfaceOnly to True to protect the user interface, but not macros (VBA code).

Microsoft documentation:

Worksheet.Protect method (Excel)

Sub LockSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws
            .Unprotect
            .Cells.Locked = False
            .Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Locked = True
            .Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        End With
    Next ws
End Sub

